# How does this bouncing off object after collision detection code work?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, game-physics

Recently I was just reading the book XNA 4.0 Game Developmeny by Example. In one the of the chapters this code is written for bouncing (reflecting) the objects after collision detection:

```
private void BounceAsteroids(Sprite asteroid1, Sprite asteroid2)
{

    Vector2 cOfMass = (asteroid1.Velocity + asteroid2.Velocity) / 2;
    Vector2 normal1 = asteroid2.Center - asteroid1.Center;
    normal1.Normalize();
    Vector2 normal2 = asteroid1.Center - asteroid2.Center;
    normal2.Normalize();

    asteroid1.Velocity -= cOfMass;
    asteroid1.Velocity = Vector2.Reflect(asteroid1.Velocity, normal1);
    asteroid1.Velocity += cOfMass;

    asteroid2.Velocity -= cOfMass;
    asteroid2.Velocity = Vector2.Reflect(asteroid2.Velocity, normal2);
    asteroid2.Velocity += cOfMass;
}
```

Can anybody explain me this code with some diagram or some example which is easy to visualize. I am not able to visualize this code. If anybody knows any book where I can learn this type of physics stuff useful for game programming then also I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is trying to simulate a bounce.

the Normalize and center calculations are making the blobs start the bounce when their edges touch, as opposed to when their centers might hit.

then the velocity is changed according to some calculation involving masses of each asteroid.

the Reflect function no doubt calculates some angles so things go in the proper direction.

Comment: Can you tell me what code I had to write if there was no Reflect method? Also, if I do not normalize the vector the object just disappears as soon as two objects edges touch and is no more in viewport.

Comment: @Anthony: that's why reflect() expects a normalized vector

Comment: @BlackBear : Ok. Can you tell me what equations I need to write if I did not use Reflect method?

Comment: @Anthony, Reflect just reflects the vector about the specified normal vector, which is the same as projecting the vector (using dot product), subtracting the projection to get the offset and then subtracting the offset from the projection to 'mirror' the vector around the normal.  If you don't know what this means, do some googling on vectors and vector math.  You'll want to understand vector mathematics and basic linear algebra if you plan to do game development, so it will be time well spent.

Comment: Be careful with this code. It averages the effect of mass between the two asteroids and applies that average to each's reflected velocity magnitudes. If the two asteroids happen to be exactly the same size (mass), then this code is 100% accurate (in the context of what I'm talking about). But if you have one big asteroid & one small asteroid, then the resulting velocity magnitudes are not so realistic/accurate. When a big one hits a small one, you would expect the small one's velocity to deviate more than the big one... not so with this code.